# Visual Studio dev container can't connect to mysql service

Tags: mysql, bitnami, vscode-devcontainer

When using a dev container in Visual Studio Code (VSC) I can't connect to the MySQL database, not even from inside the container. However, when I manually start the service with `docker-compose up -d mysql` I can connect to the database from within the container.

I'm using the Bitnami MySQL from the Docker Hub registry.

This is the content of my `.devcontainer.json`:

```json
{
    "name": "Devcontainer",
    "dockerComposeFile": "docker-compose.yml",
    "service": "devcontainer",
    "workspaceFolder": "/workspaces/${localWorkspaceFolderBasename}"
}
```

Kept is as basic as possible.

The contents of the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  devcontainer:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/base:ubuntu
    volumes:
      - ../..:/workspaces:cached

    command: sleep infinity

  mysql:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mysql:8.0
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    expose:
      - 3306
    volumes:
      - 'mysql_data:/bitnami/mysql/data'
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=no
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=deOCyZ4cnRa4bRNDAFak8
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=deOCyZ4cnRa4bRNDAFak8
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=name
    healthcheck:
      test: ['CMD', '/opt/bitnami/scripts/mysql/healthcheck.sh']
      interval: 15s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 6

volumes:
  mysql_data:
    driver: local
```

So when I do a `Rebuild without cache and reopen in container` in VSC it starts up the docker container. After that I enter the container using `docker exec -it <hash> bash` and try to login to the server:

```bash
$ mysql -u user -p 
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

When I close the remote connection and make sure the container is not running anymore I start the container with `docker-compose up -d db`.

When it's running I start bash inside the container the same way and then I can connect to the server:

```bash
$ mysql -u user -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 10
Server version: 8.0.31 Source distribution
```

I'm 100% sure I supply the correct password with copy/paste.

The same connection problems also exists for root user. I've also tried to use the `ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true` but that has the same result.

I've tried to use MariaDB version supplied by Bitnami but is has the same problem. I haven't tried the original MySQL image but I never had this problem before.

No other docker containers are running when I start the dev container.

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
$
```

Any idea what's happening and how to fix it? Am I doing something wrong?

Update: It looks like the original MySQL images from the Docker Hub are working properly.